# How to pass an ajax date to jquery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have a `datepicker`, and I want to use the picked date in a query in a Movements table, to retrieve corresponding turnover. But "`currentDate`" does not load with the `picked date` : I have a "invalid date" exception caught. How should I do it ?

```
$("#datepicker").change(function(){
        var currentDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
        var wantedTO = <%=Movement.where(:movementDate =>Date.parse("currentDate")).sum("turnover")%>;  
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ $("#result").html("<p>Result here : </p>" + wantedTO);     
        });             
    });
```

Note that if I replace

```
var wantedTO = <%=Movement.where(:movementDate =>Date.parse("currentDate")).sum("turnover")%>;
```

by

```
var wantedTO = <%=Movement.where(:movementDate =>Date.today).sum("turnover")%>;
```

it's giving me today's turnover. So I might not be so far !

EDIT : 
To be sure of the date format, I added a line

```
 var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", currentDate);
```

And checked OK that if I put a manual date in that format then, it's working. It seems that it's a problem of how to pass this variable, but I can't fix it. Any idea ?

Comment: what is the used date format

Comment: I think `Date.parse("currentDate")` should be `Date.parse(currentDate)`. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/26sT9/

Comment: Date.parse(currentDate) isn't working either. I inserted an     alert(currentdate) which is giving me the date format is : Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET). In the text box of the datepicker, it's 02/24/2013. In my base, it's 2013-02-24. Do you think it's what makes it wrong ? How do I correct it ?

Comment: See the EDIT : now I am sure to have the correct format date. But still I can't pass my date in the query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have my answer. In case other newbies would face the same problem, I will summarize it. There was a big mistake in my code : you can't do a ruby query inside the Ajax code. So waht, you have to do :

1- Create a new method (sort) in your controller (movements_controller.rb) :

```
def sort
    selected_date = params[:date]
    new_html_to_return = Movement.where(:movementDate =>Date.parse(params[:date])).sum("turnover")
    render :text => new_html_to_return
end
```

2- Create a POST ajax function in your view (index.html.erb) :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $datepicker = $("#datepicker"),
    currentDate = new Date(),
    dateString = "";

$datepicker.change(function(){
    currentDate = $datepicker.datepicker( "getDate" );
    dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", currentDate);  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        // You're sending the variable to your Ruby on Rails controller
        url: "movements/sort/",
        data: {"date":dateString},
        }).done(function(data) {
                $("#result").html("<p>Turnover: </p>" + data)
        });                         
    }); 
});
</script>
```

3- Create the associated route in your routes.rb :

```
  post "movements/sort"
```

And you're done ! Enjoy !